# Whats the highest scoring word?

Tags: words-with-friends

I've been playing words with friends for awhile now and have made some pretty high scoring words but what's the highest scoring word, ignoring bonus tile placement? What about including bonus tiles?

Depending on where letters fall and how bonus tiles align these might not be the same word.

I'd also like to know if these words are only possible with the addition of letters already on the board? If so please explain.

Comment: This is probably going to be sort of sticky to get a definitive answer for, because there's likely no way to know with certainty what the full list of words allowed by the game is, since it uses a custom list that appears to be updated from time to time. Additionally, there's no way to conclusively disprove a suggested word aside from finding a different word that scores even higher.

Comment: @PanicBomb You have a point. I hadn't considered a dynamic list of words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Words with Friends (and Scrabble), `OXYPHENBUTAZONE` is generally the highest scoring single word.

If you collaborate with a friend, you can set the board up to play this word for 1670 points (possibly more if you use different words elsewhere on the board).

[image]

[Source](http://recordsetter.com/world-record/highest-point-value-give-for-single-word-game-words-with-friends/5303)

Comment: Wow. That's a lot more then I expected.